# List Azure Resources RBAC Assignments Showing Eligible/Active

Tags: azure, azure-rbac, pim

Via PowerShell or API, is there a way to recursively or non-recursively list role assignments for azure resources at (a) given scope(s) and show whether the role assignment is Eligible or Active? The results need to be exportable to a csv file.